# Not receiving data from Facebook feed webhook

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments, facebook-webhooks

Having this problem where I'm not getting any data to feed webhook. When I try to test it on webhook->page->test It's sending data but when i actually test it it's not sending any data. But messenger webhook is working. Hope you guys can help me, been searching for solutions but not able to find one

Comment: Any please help ,me

Comment: Which webhook are you tring to implement?